# Display user's last visit on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to display the user's last visit, not the last login.
I've come across this code, which I've come to realize now, works exactly as intended, to show the last login, which is not what I want to display, since for example, I'm myself have been logged for over a week, when this is displayed, it gives the impression that I haven't been on the site for over a week (Last Seen:), which is incorrect.
I'm trying to display the last time a user was seen on the site.
Any ideas?

http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-show-users-last-login-date-in-wordpress/

```html
<?php 
/**
 * Capture user login and add it as timestamp in user meta data
 *
 */
 
function user_last_login( $user_login, $user ) {
    update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'last_login', time() );
}
add_action( 'wp_login', 'user_last_login', 10, 2 );
 
 
function wpb_lastlogin() { 
    $last_login = get_the_author_meta('last_login');
    $the_login_date = human_time_diff($last_login);
    return $the_login_date; 
} 
  
add_shortcode('lastlogin','wpb_lastlogin');
?>

<?php echo 'Last seen: '. do_shortcode('[lastlogin]') .' ago'; ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running your code on a hook "wp_login" which of course will run only when you login instead of running each time you refresh a page. The fallowing code should work each time a logged in user refreshes the site:

```
<?php 
/**
 * Capture timestamp of active user
 *
 */

function user_last_seen() {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        update_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'last_seen', time() );
    } else {
        return;
    }

}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'user_last_seen', 10 );


function wp_lastseen() { 
    $last_seen = get_the_author_meta('last_seen');
    $the_last_seen_date = human_time_diff($last_seen);
    return $the_last_seen_date; 
} 

add_shortcode('lastseen','wp_lastseen');
?>

<?php echo 'Last seen: '. do_shortcode('[lastseen]') .' ago'; ?>
```

This script will update the lastseen shortcode date each time the user refreshes a page in your site.

Comment: This works great. thank you for the answer and explanation. Somehow, out of the box it shows "last seen 48 years ago". After navigating away, it updates and shows the correct value.